# Possible To Somehow Move Third Party Package Dependencies into peerDependencies?

Tags: vue.js, peer-dependencies

I'm working on a project where some of the third party packages have included Vue as one of their Dependencies, which causes duplicate instances of Vue and the dreaded duplicate 'You are running Vue in development mode' in the console.

It's a monolith app using Vue with blade templates, each containing their own Vue app. A global Vue instance is instantiated in the app.js file, bundled using Laravel Mix.

Removing the dependencies that I can see use Vue as an actual dependency and not a peerDep fixes this.

I was wondering if there's a way to explicitly state to these packages that Vue should be a peer, thus only using the version that's in my environment.

Some examples of these packages would be:

https://github.com/karoletrych/vue-cron-editor/blob/master/package.json
https://github.com/Leecason/element-tiptap/blob/next/package.json

As you can see in their packages, they don't use Vue as a peerDep.

Any pointers really appreciated.

Comment: It's a mistake on the side of package devs to put vue to deps, but this shouldn't be really a problem. You need to use compatible vue version restrain in the project and then it will be deduped in nested packages. If this is not the case because of package lock, use npm dedupe. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce and specify your npm version as it may be responsible for how deduplication works

Comment: @EstusFlask So I have semi-solved this by moving these problem packages into the app.js file by using `Vue.use(XYZ)` or `Vue.component('example', XYZ)` basically moving them into their own plugins fixes the warnings and the duplicate console messages.